# A3 = B3, next day I will need the formula to change to A3 = B4, help please

Tags: excel

I need some big help on this.

I need to increment my cell references in a formula everytime some condition is used.

Let's say i take my data to be displayed in A3 from B3, my formula will be A3 = B3 in simple terms, but the next day I will need A3 to take data from B4 instead as B3 will be my past data already, how will I increment the formula to change to A3 = B4? Forgive me on my ignorance.

Comment: Is Column B a list, or do you populate it one by one as days change? Like today, B4 is the end of the list, tomorrow, it'll be B5, etc, etc. Or do you have a list in Column B already but you just want to change the reference based on the day?

Comment: I populate and fill in data daily, so today B4 is the end of the list but for tomorrow I will key in the new data in B5

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification in the comments above, this should work fine:

```
=OFFSET(B1,COUNTA(B:B)-1,0)
```

Input the above in `A1`. It will always return the last row in Column B (assuming your data in Column B is contiguous).

***Screenshot:***

**Set-up:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the Offset() suggestion, try in A1

```
=INDEX(B:B,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(99^99,B:B,1),0),IFERROR(MATCH("zzzzzzz",B:B,1),0)))
```

This will work with both numeric and text data. You can edit the formula to remove the Match for numbers if your file only has text in that column, and vice versa.

Key differences to the Offset() suggestion:

- this formula will return the last entry in column B, even if there are gaps and blank cells in column B
- the index/match combo formula is not volatile. Offset() is volatile and will cause the whole workbook to recalculate when any cell anywhere in the file changes. In large data models with many calculations, that can cause slowness. I a small spreadsheet, you won't notice a difference.

Comment: well explained :D although the logic is advance.